# How does Ethash work?

Tags: ethereum-classic, hash-algorithm, ethash

I've looked at the wiki in search of how the information about Ethash algorithm but I did not find the answer.

Where can I find detailed information about it or can someone explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The general route that the algorithm takes is as follows:
>
> 1. There exists a seed which can be computed for each block by scanning
>      through the block headers up until that point.
> 2. From the seed, one can
>      compute a 16 MB pseudorandom cache. Light clients store the cache.
> 3. From the cache, we can generate a 1 GB dataset, with the property that
>      each item in the dataset depends on only a small number of items from
>      the cache. Full clients and miners store the dataset. The dataset
>      grows linearly with time.
> 4. Mining involves grabbing random slices of
>      the dataset and hashing them together. Verification can be done with
>      low memory by using the cache to regenerate the specific pieces of the
>      dataset that you need, so you only need to store the cache. 
>     
>    The large
>      dataset is updated once every 30000 blocks, so the vast majority of a
>      miner's effort will be reading the dataset, not making changes to it.
>
> See
>   [Ethash-Design-Rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale)
>   for design rationale considerations for this algorithm.

---

More sources:

[Page number 15](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) of Yellow Paper.

[Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) in Ethereum wiki on github.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-blockchain-third-edition/9781839213199)

> Ethash is the name of the PoW algorithm used in Ethereum. Originally,
> this was proposed as the Dagger-Hashimoto algorithm, but much has
> changed since the first implementation, and the PoW algorithm has now
> evolved into what's known as Ethash.
>
> Similar to Bitcoin, the core idea behind mining is to find a nonce (a
> random arbitrary number), which, once concatenated with the block
> header and hashed, results in a number that is lower than the current
> network difficulty level. Initially, the difficulty was low when
> Ethereum was new, and even CPU and single GPU mining was profitable to
> a certain extent, but that is no longer the case. Now, only either
> pooled mining or large GPU mining farms are used for profitable mining
> purposes.
>
> Ethash is a memory-hard algorithm, which makes it difficult to be
> implemented on specialized hardware. As in Bitcoin, ASICs have been
> developed, which have resulted in mining centralization over the
> years, but memory-hard PoW algorithms are one way of thwarting this
> threat, and Ethereum implements Ethash to discourage ASIC development
> for mining. Ethash is a memory-hard algorithm and developing ASICs
> with large and fast memories is not feasible. This algorithm requires
> subsets of a fixed resource called Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) to be
> chosen, depending on the nonce and block headers.
>
> DAG is a large, pseudo-randomly generated dataset. This graph is
> represented as a matrix in the DAG file created during the Ethereum
> mining process. The Ethash algorithm expects the DAG as a
> two-dimensional array of 32-bit unsigned integers.
>
> Mining can only start when DAG is completely generated the first time
> a mining node starts. This DAG is used as a seed by the algorithm
> called Ethash. According to current specifications, the epoch time is
> defined as 30,000 blocks, or roughly 6 days. The Ethash algorithm
> requires a DAG file to work. A DAG file is generated every epoch,
> which is 30,000 blocks. DAG grows linearly as the chain size grows.
> Currently, the DAG size is around
> 3.5 GB (as of block 9325164) and epoch number 310.
>
> The protocol works as follows:
>
> 1. First, the header from the previous block and a 32-bit random nonce is combined using Keccak-256.
> 2. This produces a 128-bit structure called mix .
> 3. mix determines which data is to be picked up from the DAG.
> 4. Once the data is fetched from the DAG, it is "mixed" with the mix to produce the next mix , which is then again used to fetch data from
>    the DAG and subsequently mixed. This process is repeated 64 times.
> 5. Eventually, the 64th mix is run through a digest function to produce a 32-byte sequence.
> 6. This sequence is compared with the difficulty target. If it is less than the difficulty target, the nonce is valid, and the PoW is solved.
>    As a result, the block is mined. If not, then the algorithm repeats
>    with a new nonce.